# Environment variable differences when using Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, environment-variables, paramiko

I am connecting to SSH via terminal (on Mac) and run a Paramiko Python script and for some reason, the two sessions seem to behave differently. The `PATH` environment variable is different in these cases.

This is the code I run:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host', username='myuser',password='mypass')
stdin, stdout, stderr =ssh.exec_command('echo $PATH')
print (stdout.readlines())
```

Any idea why the environment variables are different?

And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working with the `Channel` object instead of the `SSHClient` object solved my problem.

```
chan=ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.send('echo $PATH\n')
print (chan.recv(1024))
```

For more details, see the [documentation](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/channel.html)

Comment: While this indeed helps, the answer fails to explain why. It's not about `Channel` vs. `SSHClient`. The `SSHClient` uses the `Channel` internally. The difference is that your original code uses an "exec" channel, which by default does not allocate pseudo terminal. While your new code uses a "shell" channel, which by default allocates a pseudo terminal. Using shell for executing commands is not good practice. And again, it's generally a bad practice to have your account configured to use a different `PATH` for interactive and non-interactive terminals.

Comment: I tried your code coz exec_command did not import modules like pandas even though i have them in my ec2. Even small py files that just wrote a new file did not work with your code. how can I get back errors from above method

Answer (score 6):

The `SSHClient.exec_command` by default does not allocate a pseudo terminal for the session. As a consequence a different set of startup scripts is (might be) sourced (particularly for non-interactive sessions, `.bash_profile` is not sourced). And/or different branches in the scripts are taken, based on an absence/presence of `TERM` environment variable.

---

To emulate the default Paramiko behavior with the `ssh`, use the `-T` switch:

```
ssh -T myuser@host
```

See the [`ssh` man](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh):

> `-T`       Disable pseudo-tty allocation.

---

Contrary, to emulate the default `ssh` behavior with Paramiko, set the `get_pty` parameter of the `exec_command` to `True`:

```
def exec_command(self, command, bufsize=-1, timeout=None, get_pty=False):
```

---

Though rather than working around the issue by allocating the pseudo terminal in Paramiko, you should better fix your startup scripts to set the same `PATH` for all sessions.

For that see [Some Unix commands fail with "<command> not found", when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55419330/850848).