# Execute command over ssh and paramiko in python

Tags: python, ssh, command, exec, paramiko

I'm writing a script that loads calculation files to a server, runs calculations and downloads the finished files again. Everything works, except the command does not. A needed command is "bbjobs" and it works fine when I'm working with WinSCP, in python with paramiko this error message arrives:

```
['bash: bbjobs: command not found\n']
```

With "which bbjobs" I found the complete path of the command. But when I try it with the complete path this error message arrives:

```
['/cluster/apps/lsf/10.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/bbjobs: error while loading shared libraries: liblsf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n']
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('host',22,'login','pwd')

(InputStream, OutputStream, Error) = ssh.exec_command('bbjobs')
print(list(OutputStream))
print(list(Error))
```

I have no idea what to do now...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you try `echo $PATH` and post the output?

Comment: ['/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin\n']

Comment: Add `/cluster/apps/lsf/10.1/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/` to your path. You might need to add the `lib` portion of that path too.

Comment: Okey I found the path of the lib file, but how can i add both paths in my command?

Comment: Particularly, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964108/850848#31966441).

Comment: Okey thank you, I didn't realize what was the problem. It turned out that when downloading and deleting the files from the server, the startup scripts which were hidden on the cluster were deleted, and therefore it did not work. Now everything works fine