# Why is an output of some commands (like an order of files in "ls" listing) different in Paramiko compared to manual SSH session?

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

When we send command using `ssh.exec_command` of Paramiko library of Python. After that we receive three parameter as output: `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`. So I want to compare the output of `stdout` with existing list. So on what basis the sorting of `stdout` result happen if I what to compare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to commands like `ls`, you may get different results based on environment variables set.

And you can get different environments based on whether a terminal is allocated for the session.

With Paramiko [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) with the `get_pty` parameter with the default value `False`, you should get the same results as with:

```
ssh user@host command
```

If you set `get_pty` to `True`, you get the same results as with:

```
ssh -T user@host command
```

But you should not set `get_pty=True`, as your code can then break when the environment changes.

Related questions with more details:

- [Environment variable differences when using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964108/850848)
- [What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848)