# Not able to run kubectl on remote using python

Tags: python-3.x, kubectl, paramiko

I am trying to run kubectl commands on a remote server from local, but seems it is trying to run on localhost when all other commands(ls, date) I am able to run on remote.

```
command = 'kubectl get pod -n namespace'
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh.exec_command(command)
```

Error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Any idea how to run kubectl on remote to connect to a pod and run some command there inside the pod?

Comment: Would this help? [Environment variable differences when using Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964108/850848).

Comment: are you using kubeconfig file in your python code ?

Comment: I am not using kubeconfig file. Can you please let me know how to use it with paramiko.

Comment: Use `--kubeconfig=` with your kubectl command.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are ssh connection is non-root user, this error comes when you try to execute the kubectl commands as non-root user.

Solutions:

1. Add sudo as prefix to the commands. This will solve the issue with current user itself.
2. Make the ssh connection with root user.

Comment: I can not run sudo with my username. 
Thanks for the suggestions.