# "Environmental Variable 'TERM' not defined" error while running executable file from shell script in a local system over SSH

Tags: python, linux, shell, ssh, terminal

There is a shell script **execute.sh** in a remote system.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running scp"

/home/lokesh/linuxx86-64/scpview  //scpview is my executable file
```

I am doing SSH to remote system from a python script.

```
    def SSH_Server_scp(hostname):
    print('running')
    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

        client.connect(hostname, port=22, username='username',
                       password='password')

        (stdin, stdout, stderr) = client.exec_command('./executescp.sh')
         
        cmd_output = stdout.read()
        print(cmd_output)
       
        return output_file
    finally:
        client.close()
 
    SSH_Server_scp('hostname')
```

The shell script is running perfectly fine when I run the script locally in a remote server, but its failing with "**Environmental Variable 'TERM' not defined**" when I invoke my shell script from python.
What is that I am missing here? I tried exporting **TERM** environmental variable also

```
export TERM=xterm
```

Please help

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31964108/1248563.
The short answer is: use `get_pty=True` in `exec_command`

Comment: @cornuz Thanks a Lot sir. It solved my problem.