# Running remote python script with paramiko exec_command doesn't work

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh, paramiko

I have Python software installed on my remote node which I can run everywhere when I'm in a ssh-session. This will read various metrics and store them in the text file.
There are reasons why these modules work like this, and I cannot change it.

```
user@node
$ read_sensors.py -p /data/log_20231213.txt
```

But now I want to automatically trigger this script from remote via SSH out of my second script.
I need this external trigger due to synchronization issues. So not possible over cronjob or similar.

Now I tried to use `fabric` but ended up using plain `paramiko`.
Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to trigger the script with `exec_command` but managed to do it with `invoke_shell`. But due as I don't now how long the script will run I would use the `stderr` for the error handling.

The sensor node runs Ubuntu and my script runs on Windows 10.

My script was so far:

```
import paramiko
import time

hostname = "192.168.1.10"
username = "user"
password = "pw"

commands = [
    "mkdir 20230212",
    "read_sensors.py"
]

# initialize the SSH client
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
# add to known hosts
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

try:
    client.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
except:
    print("[!] Cannot connect to the SSH Server")
    exit()

remote_conn = client.invoke_shell()

# execute the commands
for command in commands:
    print("="*50, command, "="*50)

    remote_conn.send(command+' \n')
    time.sleep(2)
    output = remote_conn.recv(1000)
    print(output)
```

But I could not figure out how to do it with `execc_command`. I just get the following error `bash: read_sensors.py: command not found`

```
for command in commands:
    print("="*50, command, "="*50)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read().decode())
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print(err)
```

Any ideas where I can start looking for the error?

Comment: In order to run a python script, you would at least have to use `python read_sensors.py` or `python3 read_sensors.py`. Adding `read_sensors.py` by itself does nothing, it is not a system command.

Comment: Does read_sensors.py exist on the target systems?  Maybe its done somewhere else, but the file must be copied to the target system first, then called via python like @Cow commented.  FYI ansible is perfect for that kind of thing, but there is a learning curve.

Comment: @Cow This is not true, as you can define it explicit to use python https://superuser.com/questions/828737/run-python-scripts-without-explicitly-invoking-python

Comment: @Nic3500 yes it exist on the target system. when I open a session over ssh with e.g. putty i can run the command.
And with invoke_shell it also works. Thanks for the command with ansible, I would use it, but there are very specific reasons which I don't want to explain why we're stuck on ssh

Comment: A guess here, is it possible exec_command does not load the environment like invoke_shell does?  See https://zditect.com/blog/11190727.html where it discusses the differences between both (ssh exec channel vs ssh shell channel).  EDIT: @MartinPrikryl comment is the answer!

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964108/environment-variable-differences-when-using-paramiko

Comment: finding the original path was not given by "which" - but now using the full path works