# SSH from Python into Another Unix Server and then Send Command

Tags: python, unix, ssh

I have a process I'm trying to automate that requires getting data from one server and then running a process on another. From the first server if I manually SSH into the other server and then launch my command it works, but if I put it the entire command on one line it manages to launch the process but I generate a secondary error from the Oracle server I connect to.

**Doesn't work**

```
ssh username@server {command}
```

**Works**

```
1st line - ssh username@server 
2nd line after connecting to server {command}
```

I'm trying to automate this in python and tried the following three approaches, which all managed to launch the process but gave me the oracle error.

```
import os
os.system(f'ssh username@server {command}')

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(f'ssh username@server {command}', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

import paramiko
sshcon = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshcon.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AudoAddPolicy())
sshcon.connect(hostname, username, key_filename = ssh_key_path)
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshcon.exec_command({command})
sshcon.close
```

So I am wondering through python is there a way to replicate the following two actions: log into other server through SSH in terminal, once logged into to other server send command?

Comment: Does it give you the same error each time? What's the error?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're really trying to accomplish. If `ssh username@server some-command` worked, would you need python? Or are you trying to do something more in python than just launch a remote command? Also, what's the error from the Oracle server?

Comment: The version with paramiko looks OK, you just didn't call `close`. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: What error are you getting from Oracle?

Comment: The difference between `ssh hostname command` and `ssh hostname` is that the former doesn't run the command with a controlling terminal. You can use the `-T` option to force a controlling terminal for the one-liner.

Comment: @Barmar. The oracle error is "Unable to load oracle client (libclntsh.so)"

Comment: @Larry Yes there are API calls that are easier to run through python on that server than through the other application due to IT restrictions.

Comment: I suspect it's dependent on an environment variable (e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) that you set in one of your shell startup scripts, like `.profile`. One-liners don't start a login shell, so they don't run the .profile.

Comment: @Barmar using -T or -tt I had also tried gives the same Oracle error once the script is lauched by the other program (SAS)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Any way to launch a login shell from python?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964108/environment-variable-differences-when-using-paramiko may be the solution

Comment: Do you have to set certain environment variables on the remote system for oracle to work? How are those variables normally set?